# How to convert sqlite3 data to Json format and CSV format

Tags: python, json, csv, sqlite

I have a mission to convert sqlite3 data to Json format and CSV format, I can read the data like this (line breaks added):

```
(2966, 
 u'http://buy.xineurope.com/thread-394248-1-1.html', 
 u'\u6d77\u666f\u623f\u627e\u4eba\u5408\u79df - \u623f\u5c4b\u4fe1\u606f - \u8df3\u86a4\u5e02\u573a - \u65b0\u6b27\u6d32-XinEurope-\u534e\u4eba\u4fe1\u606f\u5a31\u4e50\u4e92\u52a8\u95e8\u6237 - Powered by Discuz!', 
 1, 0, 12979085330693664L, 0, 0)
```

Is there some tools or modules (`import json`?) that help me to transfer, and the most import thing is what are the formats about json and CSV, could you give me a example use the data above?

Just like, I create a dict {'a':dad,'b':dada}, but in json format?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant CSV (Comma-Separated Values), not CVS (a version control system).

Comment: only 10 years later, but could try: https://github.com/liquidaty/zsv/blob/main/docs/csv_json_sqlite.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert to `json`, whether it's one row or `cursor.fetchall()`:

```
import json

json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

or use `json.dump(some_file_object, data)` if you want to store it to a file.

To convert to `csv`:

```
import csv

writer = csv.writer(some_file_object)

for row in cursor:
    # the csv module can't handle unicode, so encode the strings
    row = [item.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(item, basestring) else item 
                                                                for item in data]
    writer.writerow(row)
```